# Creating PDF file using Swift on Ubuntu

Tags: swift, pdf, ubuntu-14.04, vapor

I have a Swift/Vapor app running on Ubuntu. It responds to and serves back JSON, i.e. a pure RESTful server.

I am looking to add some functionality where it can produce a PDF file, and then sends this back to the front-end (a web browser) in response to some request.

Could anyone recommend a best way of creating the PDF file on the server for sending back?

Comment: Have you tried using this: https://github.com/vapor-community/wkhtmltopdf It seems to generate a pdf from a Leaf/HTML page. Don't know if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Look's like what I might need - let me give it a go and share my results...

Answer (score 2):

I tried wkhtmltopdf, but couldn't get it to work satisfactorily. I now use weasyprint on both macOS and Ubuntu (on a raspberry pi).

I use this function:

```
 func generateWeasy(html: Bytes) -> Bytes {
  // Fetch a PDF from WeasyPrint and return it
  let weasy = Process()
  let input = Pipe()
  let output = Pipe()
  let htmlData = Data(html)
  weasy.standardInput = input
  weasy.standardOutput = output
  weasy.launchPath = "/usr/local/bin/weasyprint"
  weasy.arguments = ["-f", "pdf", "-", "-"]
  weasy.launch()
  input.fileHandleForWriting.write(htmlData)
  input.fileHandleForWriting.closeFile()
  return output.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile().makeBytes()
}
```

Then to render a view into PDF, I use standard leaf inside a route:

```
html = try self.view.make("pdfCertificate", settings).makeBytes()
```

I then modify the response header and generate the PDF:

```
let response = Response(status: .ok, body: .data( self.generateWeasy( html:html )))
response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "filename=\"" + title + " - Certificates.pdf\""
return response
```